# Email not sent from journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, email-studio

I have created a journey in Marketing cloud where I'm using the lead record directly from Salesforce as the entry source and just ending the email to the record from the journey.
What is happening is that the journey is getting started and a email is sent but not received. When I check the tracking of the journey emails, I see one email is sent but to no recipient.

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Can you check if a subscriber record was created in EMail Studio (Subscribers > All Subscribers) for your lead and its status is Active?

Also make sure in salesforce, Email Opt Out , check box has the visibility (in field level security) for the profile which is used to integrate with Marketing Cloud.

Comment: is it mandatory that the lead record should be a subscriber in Email Studio or can we do this without having it present as a subscriber. Also, is there a way in which we can have records in the Journey entry source on real time basis?

Comment: It's not mandatory that lead should be in all subscribers, but if an email was send then definitely it will be in All Subscribers. If you are using a Salesforce Data Event , then it's a real time integration. Based on your criteria, when you create or edit a lead it will enter the journey.

Comment: I have done the same where when I have taken salesforce data as the entry source and Leads as the objects and the event is created. But still whenever a lead is created in Salesforce then no email is sent to the lead from the Journey Builder.

Comment: Understood, that's why you have to check if a subscriber was created in All Subscribers.